# After upgrading from 18.04 LTS to 20.4 LTS: no applications or other files known

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade

It was more than time to upgrade, I still was running 18.04 on my principal workstation. Performed *do-release-upgrade* with not a single issue, am now at 20.04 LTS and of course the next step will be to go right to 22.04 LTS.
One single inconveniency, though, even if it is not "mortal": when I want to start up an application, say "Spider Solitaire" for a simple stupid example, I used to click in the upper left corner of the gnome desktop ("Search you computer") and when entering even just one single letter a plethora of options would show up, including what I wanted.

Since the upgrade, this is no longer working: I can still click the "Search your computer" in the upper left corner, but it will now only respond "Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search". Same effect when searching for images, videos, music.

Sure enough, the "Spider Solitaire" is still present: from a terminal window I can type "sol" and presto there is the good old game.

Perhaps there is some kind of index or cache that needs to be refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tracker reset -r
tracker daemon -s
```

see: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/tracker-reset.1.html

If it will not help, then try `gsettings reset org.gnome.shell app-picker-layout`.

Comment: tried all three, no improvement

Comment: Last one yielded  No such key “app-picker-layout”

Comment: Okay... I don't have idea why it wouldn't work, but maybe you can wait for other answers, or try: `sudo dconf reset -f /org/gnome/` but note this command is invasive and will reset whole GNOME configurations, that you will need to set again. But this works most of the times. It will also automatically disable all extensions.

I also recommend to restart GNOME by `ALT + F2` and writing `r`, then press enter.

Comment: tracker status
Currently indexed: 0 files, 0 folders
Remaining space on database partition: 3.4 GB (11.71%)
All data miners are idle, indexing complete

Comment: Executed (as root) dconf reset -f /org/gnome/ : still no change

Comment: Four days later, no change in behaviour, no further replies in this thread. Do I need to file a bug report?

Comment: Excuse me for being disappointed at the lack of answers, let alone a solution. What more can I do to get help?